# Invite a facebook friend to join in a contest

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We're holding a contest on our website. I want to require the user to invite one facebook friend to join the user on the trip that the user might win.

Facebook has stopped supporting /me/friends in such a way that it won't give us a friend list, unless the friends have also connected with our application.

Any suggestions for alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 types of requests:

1. user to user (when your app is unauthorized)
2. app to user (when the app is authorized)

You need to send a user-user invite via the requests dialog if the user hasnt authorized your app.
Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.0#invites

If the user has authorized the app you can send an app-user invite.

Also, do note that with the v2.0 of the new facebook api, you need to explicitly get a permission from your user of "user_friends"

Comment: Will I be able to know who was invited when using the user-to-user invite?

Comment: you'll have to maintain a local list of ids to whome you have sent the request on your side. This is fine since, multiple users may send an invite to the same person. And for your query, when you send a user-user apprequest, you get the list of invited facebook ids as a CSV, so you can keep track of that

Comment: Thank you! You sent me exactly where I needed to look :)